# Magento 2.4.5: Uncaught ReferenceError: affirm is not defined

Tags: magento2

I got the error from js file in checkout page. The error was thrown from the below lines
affirm.ui.ready(function(){affirm.checkout(JSON.parse(response))

Here how to declare the affirm.

Comment: Hi, can you please share the error from the console as a screenshot, and please do share the JS file from where you are getting this error , Since to declare this affirm I need to know if it is a UI component or any widget that may be used, need more info on this error to debug?

Answer (score 0):

I have also same error, someone can help me please:
File location: `vendor/affirm/magento2/view/frontend/web/js/action/inline-checkout.js`
[image]